# Execute code freemarker into a freemarker ftl

Tags: spring, freemarker

I am trying to execute freemarker code within a freemarker ftl, I explain a little what I have:

We have a module with Spring that solves the FTL views and prints its content, even here everything works perfectly, but sometimes we will want to introduce more code in that view and we need to do it without having to deploy the module again, that is why we are entering Freemarker code in a *String* variable and passing that variable to the view through the model. But the problem appears here, I don't know how to manage that variable, the most I can do is paint it $ {myVar}, but the Freemakrer code appears as if it were a simple HTMl (that is, Freemarker does not execute it as such).

Is there a way to do a kind of include with that variable that has Freemarker code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something alike with dymanic parts in a view. You can use [`interpret`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_interpret) and `<@var>` to achieve that. Something like

```
<#assign varTempl = myVar?interpret >
<@varTempl />
```

The first line will parse your template, the second line will print it.

Comment: works! A question, we have our own variables (which we pass through model.setAttribute) that we are using in the code of that variable, would there be any possibility of being able to pass said object to that sentence?

Comment: To which sentence? The whole model is available to the interpreter so anything that is there is available.

Comment: You are absolutely right in the world, it works perfectly and has access to all the data of the model, I have checked the code and it contains some errors, but after solving it I see is just what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that you don't really need to create a variable for this, as you can just write `<@myVar?interpret />`.